# can neo4j property value be a dictionary

Tags: neo4j

I want to assign a dictionary as node property value. When I try to assign it a dictionary it throws an error if cyphertype saying only arrays or primitive data types can be assigned. So the question is that is there any work around to this problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to assign a dictionary as a single node property value.

But you can assign each key in the dictionary as a single property and save the dictionary that way.

```
WITH {params}
MATCH (n:Node)
SET n += params
```